# using the $.post function in jquery

Tags: jquery

The script URL that is being invoked by this jquery post method isn't executing. Here's the code for the same. Please tell me if my code is syntactically wrong or if there is some other problem with it.

```
 $.post(url,{ subject: pmSubject.val(), message: pmTextArea.val(), senderName:     sendername.val(), senderID: senderid.val(), rcpntName: recName.val(), rcpntID: recID.val(),      thisWipit: pm_wipit.val() } ,           function(data)
            {
               $('#pmb').slideUp("fast");
               $("#interactionResults").html(data).show().fadeOut(10000);
               document.pmForm.pmTextArea.value='';
               document.pmForm.pmSubject.value='';
               });
```

Comment: What are you passing as the url variable? What does the browser's debugger say?

Comment: Firstly I'd take all the effects and DOM manipulation out until you've got the actual ajax call working. Remove everything in your callback function and print the returned data to the console - if the data doesn't come back at least you're only working with your ajax call and not a load of DOM manipulation too!

Comment: The url variable is a php script which is responsible for parsing the message that is being sent in this code which is a part of a larger code which is responsible for sending private messages to other users on the website. The browser does not indicate any error as such. Nothing happens.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the data type to the request aswell, also stringify the json. So,

```
$.post(url, JSON.stringify({ 
          subject: pmSubject.val(), 
          message: pmTextArea.val(), 
          senderName: sendername.val(), 
          senderID: senderid.val(), 
          rcpntName: recName.val(), 
          rcpntID: recID.val(),
          thisWipit: pm_wipit.val() 
      }), function(data) {
             $('#pmb').slideUp("fast");
             $("#interactionResults").html(data).show().fadeOut(10000);
             document.pmForm.pmTextArea.value='';
             document.pmForm.pmSubject.value='';
         }, 'json');
```